# Angularjs + laravel REST API + socket.io event broadcast

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, laravel-5.3

I was playing arroudnd with Laravel and angularjs. I have My back end (REST API) written in Laravel 5.3 and my front end in angularjs.

I just found out about Events in laravel, My requirement is I want to send notifications to a particular user. Consider, An admin and list of users {A,B,C}
The admin wants to notify user A about his account activation.

In a real time scenario how can i display/implement displaying notifications to particular user from my REST Api to angularjs front end.

I found about Redis and Socket.io but dont exactly understund how to implement it in my scenario.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: REST is stateless. If you want real time sockets you need a php websockets library . Beyond that this question is far too broad

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the reply. can you suggest any library that can help me developing as per my requirement.

Comment: @WaseemAkram I need to do same functionality. If you have used any library than let me know.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar i was able to achieve, i just dint upload my answer

Comment: @NisargBhavsar I dint use any library, you just need to install node and add your socket code running in background(if using AWS service) and use the laravels Broadcast class to post your notification.